# How to update a data in a reducer state property in react/redux, when we don't know the level of nesting for the data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have an array or objects named "properties"

This properties array has objects in the following format:

```js
{
  "some-unique-key-A": {
    name:"someName1",
    value: {
      "some-unique-key-B": {
        name:"someName11",
        value : "someValue2"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here we don't know what is the nesting-level of that key value pairs. We just know one thing, data is to be updated for key : "some-unique-key-X"

In this case how can we update the x-level nested data immutably?

Comment: My guess would be to create a recursive function. Pass in the "node" and check the name. If it isn't correct, then pass on the node to look in again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved this
I created a recursive function which will accept a 'deep copy' (not shallow copy) of some object and the unique key in which value needs to be updated. It updation is done for the given key, it returns the updated object to be stored as the value of previous recursive object's value which was waiting for the result. In the end it just replaces the original state's object with the new one. I don't know if it mutates the state or not (perhaps it do mutates), but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Use a flat one level state of props ! Immutable is not easy to recurse, normalize your state with one level, easy to connect ;)